# WordPress localization is not working on plugin

Tags: php, localization, wordpress

I have a plugin to be translated. I have done following tasks:

Loaded the TextDomain:

```
$my_td = 'mysignup';
function my_signup_textdomain_init() {
    global $my_td;
    load_plugin_textdomain( $my_td, false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'my_signup_textdomain_init');
```

Added language files(po, pot, mo) in wp_plugin_folder\my_signup\languages (for Bengali bn_BD):

- mysignup.pot
- mysignup.mo
- bn_BD.po
- bn_BD.mo

Changed the language code in wp_config.php file:

```
define('WPLANG', 'bn_BD');
```

But problem is nothing is changed. I am not sure what i have done as mistake. I already read lots of articles and answers. Still i need help to know how can i test everything is fine that i have done and how can i solve the issue.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean `global $my_td;`  what is `global $nl_td;` ??

Comment: please check the first line of my code. `$my_td = 'mysignup';`

Comment: yes, I saw , but it is a different variable .. `$my_td != $nl_td ` .. does `$nl_td == "typo"` ??

Comment: thanks. sorry, it was my typing mistake :(

Comment: the mistake was only here in SE or in the code as well ? is it working now ? if yes, please accept answer to close. if not - elaborate on problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - what is global `$nl_td;`  did you mean global `$my_td;` ?

Second - you seem to miss the `.po` file  ( e.g. `mysignup.po` ) - and you do not need `bn_BD.po` and `bn_BD.mo`

Third - try to load like this ( without the unnecessary variable ) :

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'mysignup', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
```

Fourth  - Make sure ALL your strings are like so : `__('string','mysignup');`

**EDIT I** after comment :

In your comment you wrote :

> __('First Name field is required', $nl_td) and _e('First Name field is required', $nl_td)

Again - As far as I can tell from your very restricted code - `$nl_td` is not defined . `$my_td` is defined .

Just replace all those variables with a simple string `mysignup` .

Your code is probably some kind of `cut&paste` - but you must understand what those variables mean if you want them to work correctly, or make sure they are consistent all over .

**Edit II**( now that you edited comment from `$nl_td` to `$my_td` it seems you start to understand - edit also your code .. :-) then it will work as long as it is global. but better just write a string . )

Comment: my strings are as `__('First Name field is required', $my_td)` and `_e('First Name field is required', $my_td)`. Also followed your suggestion. but bad luck again. :(

Comment: yes it is working, when i replaced the variable with string. thanks

Comment: good . and do not forget to delete `bn_BD.po` and `bn_BD.mo` - you do not need them if you do things correctly.

Comment: I have no idea what your plugin is doing , how it is written or how it supposed to work , or how the rest of the site is . Right now if you have changed all the strings it is the correct way for loading text domain in a plugin. I think other problems are best  for another question ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41316/discussion-between-itskawsar-and-obmerk-kronen)

Comment: anyway, one last question. if i need to add 2 or more language pack, then how will i do that? let me open another question.

Comment: Please open a new question for that . It is totally out of the scope of the original question . ( but basically you just need to make new `.po .mo` files and put them in the folder.